# Thermostat code for molecular dynamics with angle dependent potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, angular-momentum, molecular-dynamics, soft-matter

I'm building molecular dynamics code for the specific purpose of simulating Janus particle because no package supports the custom angle dependent potential to my knowledge.

I'm building thermostat part and I'm encountered with the problem of angular momentum. Since usual molecular dynamics uses the thermostat for the velocity of the center of mass of each particle, I didn't concern with angular velocity. However, there is angular momentum for Janus particle (hence torque update is performed each time step) so I think I should incorporate thermostat for that.

If I'm correct, is there any formalism or reference to build the langevin thermostat(or any stochastic thermostat) code?

Comment: Just searching 'langevin thermostat molecular dynamics' in Google led me to [this Drexel.edu page](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~cfa22/msim/node34.html) that seems to have what you're looking for (but I'm no expert in MD, so I can't really judge)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I cannot find any information about how to handle the angular momentum with the langevin thermostat in this page.

Comment: [LAMMPS](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_howto.html#howto-14) supports rotational dynamics of particles with anisotropic interactions. You could look at its implementation of the Langevin dynamics, and perhaps it can even handle the anisotropic pair potential you are interested in using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to answer this question, as you do not specify what you want from your thermostat. For example, do you want to reproduce a specific kinetics (overdamped, underdamped, *etc*) or not? Do you need a deterministic or a stochastic thermostat?

- If you are only interested in the thermodynamics (and hence you don't care about the kinetics and dynamics) then the simplest (working) thermostat you can use is the Andersen thermostat. With this thermostat, the particles' momenta (velocity and angular velocity) are extracted anew from a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. The time interval between two refresh procedures is chosen randomly and it is controlled by a parameter $\nu$, which sets the coupling between the thermostat and the system. A slightly more sophisticated thermostat has been introduced [here](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3153843).
- A slightly more complicated option is the Bussi-Donadio-Parrinello thermostat (firstly introduced [here](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2408420)), which is an upgrade of the Berendsen thermostat and has lately gained a lot of attention. In contrast with the latter, it has been shown to correctly sample the canonical ensemble. It can be straightforwardly extended to the rotational degrees of freedom.
- If you want a slightly more realistic dynamics you can use a Langevin thermostat. The simplest option is to add to the equations of motion of the angular velocity a friction and a random term, the way you do for the translational degrees of freedom. However, please note that the rotational diffusion coefficient $D_r$ of a sphere with no-slip boundary conditions is related to the translational diffusion coefficient, $D_t$, *via* the relation $D_r = 3 / \sigma^2 D_t$, where $\sigma$ is the diameter of the particle. In a Langevin thermostat the diffusion coefficient is, in turn, linked through the fluctuation-dissipation relation to the friction coefficient $\gamma = T / D$. As a result, the friction coefficients for the rotational and translational degrees of freedom differ by a factor of 3.
  There are also some variants that explicitly take into account rotational degrees of freedom and are optimised to work with rigid bodies. See for example [this](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4999771) recent paper and references therein.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem as yours. I am looking for the code about thermostat with angular momentum.
I am using LAMMPS, but it cannot handle the angular momentum well and the energy cannot be conserved while rotation energy is calculated. I cannot understand how the source code works and Nose-Hoover thermostat change the temperature of the system.

Maybe you can have a try to read this parper about the model(you can find some information in the last part "simulation method"):

*Shintani, Hiroshi, and Hajime Tanaka. "Frustration on the way to crystallization in glass." Nature Physics 2.3 (2006): 200.*

Howerver, the article provide no coding details, only the physical equation about the extended thermostat. I hope it can help you.